# django login view not respecting 'next' parameter

Tags: django

I'm using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view for authentication.

In **settings.py**

```
 LOGIN_URL : 'accounts/signin/'
```

when request comes like: 
/accounts/signin/?next=/polls/books/

After successful authentication , it should redirect to `/polls/books/`
and view for that looks like:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/signin/', redirect_field_name='next')
    def category_polls(request, catslug=False):
        # all polls of a category
        cat = db.get_category(type=catslug)
        poll_obj = db.get_polls(category=cat.id)
        data={}
        data['poll_obj'] = poll_obj
        return render_to_response("polls/category_polls.html", data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

which it does not doing, rather redirect to default value of LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL("/accounts/profile/").

what am i missing here?

Comment: Have you created a custom login view (which would not handle ?next) value?

Comment: no, its django default view that being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your login form include a hidden field with a name of "next"? If not you'll need to add one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

Django will attempt to populate the field specified by `redirect_field_name` with the value from the querystring. This value is then passed back to the view in the POST, and if populated, will redirect to the url specified.